# Calling jam from Makefile does not work

Tags: makefile, cygwin, jam

In my *makefile* I was trying to go into a different directory and invoke *jam* with something like:

```
jam-build:
    cd <somedirectory> && jam <target>
```

This did not work, but caused "Unknown target. Please edit 'Jamrules'." even though the exact same command on the command line works perfectly. So I know that *jam* can find the target.

I also tried

```
jam-build:
    sh -c "cd <somedirectory> && jam <target>"
```

and variations with the same results. Also this works perfectly from the command line.

Any other command instead of "jam " works as expected (ls, ps, cat, pwd).

Update: Even creating a Makefile in <somedirectory> and running *make* there gives the same result.

Any ideas to why this happens would be appreciated. And, of course, things to try.

I'm running cygwin with latest gnu make, FT-jam 2.5.2.

Comment: The `Jamrules` file is in `<somedirectory>` and running `jam jam-build` or `jam <target>` from in that directory in the shell works? But using that same `<target>` in the makefile command doesn't work? What does `jam --version` (or equivalent) and `type -a jam` return in your shell and in your makefile?

Comment: Exactly the same things: **$ type -a jam && jam -v
jam is /usr/bin/jam
FT-Jam 2.5.2. OS=CYGWIN**. and **$ make 
cd <otherdir>  && type -a jam && jam -v
jam is /usr/bin/jam FT-Jam 2.5.2. OS=CYGWIN**
 Very strange...